# Single line graph/chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

***UPDATED I WAS ABLE TO ADD THE DATES< BUT THE ARE ALL CLUMPED TOGETHER

Can someone please help me with the below. I have looked online and have not had much luck finding something similar to my question that can help me or I just dont always understand what they are doing.

I am looking to have a little dot on a single Y axis that represents total income and that changes when I click on the teams different year on the right hand side.

below is the code I have so far and what it produces:

```
>>async function main(){

//parameters -------------------------------------------------
var w = 500;
var h = 600;
padding = 60;
//Data ------------------------------------------------------
var dataset = await d3.csv("payroll2.csv");
dataset = dataset.map(d=>({
            Year: parseInt(d["yearID"]),
            Team: d["teamID"],
            Name: d["name"],
            Salary: parseInt(d["salary"])
            }));
//Y Axis & Scale --------------------------------------------
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([240, 0])
           .range([0+padding, h-padding]);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
          .scale(yScale)
          .tickFormat(d3.format(".0f"));
//svg --------------------------------------------------------
var svg=d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width",w)
        .attr("height",h);
//Call -------------------------------------------------------
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "yaxis")
.attr("transform", "translate("+padding+",0)")
.call(yAxis);
};

//Text ----------------------------------------------------------------      
svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(preData)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            //.attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("font-size", 20)
            .attr("x", 200)
            .attr("y", function(d,){return 150})
            .attr("text-anchore", "left")
            .text(function(d){return d["Year"]});

main();
```

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like but just for one team:

[image]

SO right now I am just looking to have it show the dot and years for a single team.

I am using Javascript with d3.js in google console.

I am not sure what the actual heading would be, but any help on anything would be appreciated

Comment: your `x` and `y` attr functions are constants so all the text end up on the same spot

Comment: @rioV8 could you provide an example on what I need to fix to correct that as I have tried playing around with function(d){return}, but am having no luck

Comment: If you provide me the full list of requirements and the due date